# Django Project not being served by Apache

Tags: django, apache

My Django project is not being served while running on Apache 2.2.
All I can see is the folder structure upon hitting the URL of the domain name.
I've mod_wsgi installed but I think it's not linked well.
Can anybody tell what may be the problem?

Here's the URL of the website
http://ccbstca.ccbst.info/

Comment: The Django documentation is pretty clear about what you need to configure to make mod_wsgi work, and - as demonstrated by the link you posted for Vinayak - you don't seem to have done any of it. Go and read the [deployment documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/), follow it, and come back with any specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 1**

You need to install and enable mod_wsgi for apache. And specify WSGIScriptAlias in apache virtual host config. This link might help:

http://thecodeship.com/deployment/deploy-django-apache-virtualenv-and-mod_wsgi/

**ORIGINAL**

I think You need to name your wsgi script file as a python file (.py)

And following wsgi code might just help:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "ppbase.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

If you can post your apache virtual host config file, it would help in answering this.

Comment: It's too long does not fit in here.. How do I post it??

Comment: You can post the lines where you link the wsgi script to apache. Where you specify 'wsgi'*

Comment: I've shared the link. please refer.

Comment: Check my update to the answer. I dont see any reference to wsgi in your current config. You need to specify it using WSGIScriptAlias